# Magento bulk update product attributes (Clicking SAVE) redirects to dashboard and doesn't save

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7, bulk

Magento bulk update product attributes (Clicking SAVE) redirects to dashboard and doesn't save.

Only started happening after custom stock status by Amasty was installed but disabling this does not fix it.

I use this feature quite heavily so I know It has only stopped working within the last week. My developers can't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to enable logging? Is anything printed in the system.log/exception.log/apache error log?

Comment: yes tried.. but nothing is logged related to this issue